# Jquery slideToggle prompted by a separate link on the page

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to have a link at the top of my page open a section between headers in my site, the header (or headers) in this case have id's and these are referenced in the links ('href="#heading_3"'). I would like to use jquery only for this purpose.

```js
var _aTag = "a";
var _Header = "h3, h4";
$(document).ready(function(){
$(_aTag).click(function(){
  $element = $(this);
  $elString = $element.attr('href');
  $elString = $elString.substring(1);
  if ($element.attr('class') == 'ToCh') {
        $header = document.getElementById($elString);
     $content = $header.parent().nextUntil(_Header);
        $content.slideToggle();
   }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ToCh" href="#heading_3"> Test link</a>
<h2 id="heading_2">Header W</h2>
<p>Text</p>
<h3 id="heading_3">Header X</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<h4 id="heading_4">Header Y</h4>
<p>Text</p>
<h4 id="heading_5">Header Z</h4>
<p>Text</p>
```

Comment: Well first of all document.getElementById($elString) doesn't return a jQuery object.
Use **$($elString)** if $elString contains the id of the element you want.

Comment: I want the content after/next to the element with the $elString id

Comment: Then you could do this:
$($elString).next()

Comment: Then I'm not sure how to pull the element whose id is $elString, to then effectively use next(). Beginner here... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example on how to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.ToCh').click(function(){
            var $element = $(this);
            var linkString = $element.attr('href');
            var $content = $(linkString).next();

            $content.slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Note that I select an anchor with the required class first in stead of checking later in the code.
Also note that in order to select an element by id you need to apply # before the id string so there is no need to remove it in your case.